# To printf a matrix

Tags: c

When i want to print a matrix which i input,i can use code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n, m; //row and column
    printf("Enter row and column:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int x[n][m];
    printf("Enter your matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //input my matrix
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &x[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("print it:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //print it
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", x[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k1sE.png)(a possible case)
In code above, I have to assign values to the rows and columns of the matrix,which named "n" and "m".

```
int n, m;
scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
```

But now I am asking a way to automatic tally .
Can I get this one directly?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wZn8.png)

Comment: You seem to be asking if you need to create a 2d array to print out a 2d array. The answer of course, is yes. How else would you intend on storing the data? A 1D array with an offset in each element index to mimic a 2d array?

Comment: If you don't know the size of the matrix, I doubt you'll be able to print it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a two-dimensional array with a one-dimensional array, if that's what you mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIGITS 3

int main(void) { // It's good practice to fill function arguments with void if not planning on using them
 

  /* scanf("%d %d", &n, &m); Using scanf with uninitialised variables will result in 
   * undefined behaviour if it is unable to convert the input.  Using fgets
   * is easier to debug, safer, and cleaner.
   * I highly recommend this: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html
   */

  char buf[DIGITS+1];
  printf("%s", "Enter array rows:");
  fgets(buf, DIGITS+1, stdin);

  const int n = atoi(buf);
  
  printf("%s", "Enter array columns:");
  fgets(buf, DIGITS+1, stdin);
  
  const int m = atoi(buf);
  
  int x[n*m];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      printf("Enter array value at %d, %d: ", i, j);
      fgets(buf, DIGITS+1, stdin);
      x[i+j] = atoi(buf);
    }
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      printf("%d ", x[i+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure as to why you would do this when C supports your two-dimensional array answer equally.

Answer (score 0):

> But now I am asking a way to automatic tally.  Can I get this one directly?

Yes.

---

Form a linked-list of *lines*.  Initially the list is empty.

Read the first line of input, the `"1 2 3"` into a *string*.  Use `fgets()`.
Parse the line to detect the number of values in it.
Append the line to the linked list of lines.

Continue doing so until 1) end-of-file, 2) a blank line or 3) number of integer is not the same as the first (error condition).

Now code has the `m` (number of values per line) and `n`, the number of lines.
Form `int x[n][m];`
Parse the lines for values and save in `x`.